# Mesh clipping along a plane

Tags: mesh, intersection, plane, open3d

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4UMI.png) I would like to ask if anyone knows how to get the intersection points between the plane and the triangle-mesh or change their color (like in the photo). I know that by using this function (`clip_plane()` frome open3d) the intersection between mesh and plane will produced and a new mesh is saved. but is there any direct methods to get the Points too.
Also, if the mesh was watertight before, how can i close it again afterwards?
I tried the function `fill_holes()` with `hole_size: float = 100000000` but unfortunately the mesh remains open. Are there any other methods ?

```
clip_plane()
fill_holes()
```

I expected a watertight mesh with intersection points with the plane like in the image

Comment: What image? You failed to include one.

Comment: ooh sorry  i canot add the immage but hier can you find what i mean 
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/121578726/248031011-6cf50821-418b-4585-8890-1f147dc3ec45.png

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible the paint the points in space because your points are not continuous. Instead, you can color the triangles that has distance less than a threshold value. Also you can follow the same approach, iterate through each points and check if its Euclidian distance is less than a value; then you can give it a color as well. Following snippet should give you a direction:

```
triangle_faces = np.asarray(mesh.triangles)

intersected_indices = []

for i, face in enumerate(triangle_faces):
    v0 = triangle_vertices[face[0]]
    v1 = triangle_vertices[face[1]]
    v2 = triangle_vertices[face[2]]

    distances = a * v0[0] + b * v0[1] + c * v0[2] + d, \
                a * v1[0] + b * v1[1] + c * v1[2] + d, \
                a * v2[0] + b * v2[1] + c * v2[2] + d

    if any(abs(dist) < 0.005 for dist in distances):
        intersected_indices.append(i)
```

I am not familiar with python API, but you are welcome for further clarification if answer is not clear.